# Analytical solution for equation with power $n \in [1, 2]$

Tags: quadratics

Does there exist analytical solution to the equation $ax^p + bx + c = 0$ where $p \in [1, 2]$? Please provide references if the answer is affirmative.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
Only numerical or approximate answers.

If you know something about
the coefficients,
you can possibly establish a region
where the root(s) might be.

For example,
if you can show that
$f(x) = ax^p + bx + c$
satisfies
$f'(x) > 0$,
then it can have at most one root.

Then
looking at $f(0)$ and $f(1)$
might provide a region
where the root has to be.

Comment: If you take $n=1.5$ and solve on $\mathbb{R}_+$, taking $y=\sqrt{x}$, is it not the same as finding the positive solutions to $ay^3+by^2+c=0$ which can be done analytically?

Answer (score 0):

*After marty cohen's answer.*

SInce we look for the zero, assuming $a \neq 0$, divide all terms by $a$ and consider that you look for the zero(s) of  function $$f(x) = x^p + \beta x + \gamma$$ Because of the non integer value of $p$, we are restricted to the range $x> 0$.

The derivatives
$$f'(x)=p\, x^{p-1}+\beta \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)= (p-1) p \,x^{p-2}$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\left(-\frac{\beta}{ p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p-1}}$$ which is real if $\beta<0$. Since $f(0)=\gamma$, we also need $\gamma <0$.

If this is the case, there is one root. To approximate it, we can have an  estimate building a second order Taylor expansion around $x=x_*$ to get
$$x_0=x_* + \sqrt{-2 \frac {f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

For illustation puproses, let us try $p=1.234$, $\beta=2.345$; $\gamma=-3456$. This will give $x_*=15.5443$ and $x_0=458.481$. Now, using Newton method, the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 458.481388028 \\
 1 & 1379.34417348 \\
 2 & 1196.22489568 \\
 3 & 1191.45000524 \\
 4 & 1191.44650168
\end{array}
\right)$$

Notice that we have one overshoot of the solution because $f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) <0$ (Darboux theorem).

Answer (score 0):

There are series solutions if $b/(cp)$ is small.
If $w = (-c/a)^{1/p}$ and $v = b/(cp)$,

$$x = w + w^2 v + \frac{(3-p)}{2!} w^3 v^2 + \frac{(4-p)(4-2p)}{3!} w^4 v^3 + \frac{(5-p)(5-2p)(5-3p)}{4!} w^5 b^4 + \ldots $$